# Recommended way to deserialize a JSON from an httpClient response

Tags: json, performance, serialization, stream, httpclient

I am trying to understand the recommended way of parsing a JSON into an object, particularly from httpClient responses (but my question may also relate to parsing JSON from streams in general)

I have scoured the Internet reading many blog posts and that's what I have come up with:

I understand that parsing a stream to a string and then parsing the string to an object is a big no-no in terms of memory usage.
And according to many blog posts I have come across the traditional way of doing it, is or used to be working with streams, using the package Newtonsoft.JSON as follows:

```
using var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
using var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);
var myDeserializedObject = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<MyObject>(jsonTextReader);
```

But then I have come across another way of doing it:
If you are using .NET Core 3 and above (not so sure about the version) you have a built-in way of deserializing the stream using System.Text.JSON:

```
var myDeserializedObject = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<MyObject>(stream);
```

and particularly to httpClient requests (and if you are using .NET 5 and above if I am not mistaken)
you can do:

```
var myDeserializedObject = httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<MyObject>();
```

Please if someone could explain the ups and downs (if there are any) of each approach, especially in terms of performance and memory usage.

Comment: There isn't really a noticeable difference there. It's basically the same thing. The library was only created as there was no built-in way to do this. If you don't have a particular reason to use Newtonsoft, use the built-in one as you then don't have an external dependency and you'll have the built-in one included anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My company has been discussing the something of a similar situation. We ended with the following considerations .

Using Newtonsoft.JSON:

Pros:

- A widely used library with a lot of features, including serializing and deserializing JSON.
- Provides good control over the serialization and deserialization process.

Cons:

- Can consume more memory due to string conversion of the JSON stream.
- May have performance overhead when serializing and deserializing large JSON payloads.

Using System.Text.Json:

Pros:

- Built-in and optimized for performance in .NET Core 3 and above.
- Consumes less memory compared to Newtonsoft.JSON.
- Has improved performance compared to Newtonsoft.JSON.

Cons:

- Has limited options for customizing the serialization and deserialization process.
- May not have all the features available in Newtonsoft.JSON.

For most cases, System.Text.Json should be sufficient for deserializing JSON payloads. However, for more complex JSON serialization/deserialization requirements, Newtonsoft.JSON may still be the preferred choice. Ultimately, the choice depends on the specific requirements of the project if there are any guiding and limitations for your project.

Answer (score 0):

`httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<>()`:
Cons:

- Doesn't support `204 NoConent` (not sure if they fixed it by now).
- More over, if any error occurs during the call you have to handle the `HttpRequestException` exception to get the status code.
- Needs some hackish way to have more control over an API call (e.g., To limit the reader stream buffer, you should get the underlying stream using `httpClient.GetStreamAsync()` and then do `JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync()` and apply limitation there).
- You don't have the luxury of returning `JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable()` for the better performance where the size of each item in the list is huge and takes time to be deserialized.
- It negligibly violates Single Responsibility Principle by doing both API call and deserialization.

Pros:

- It's a beloving simple way of doing API calls.

Comment: No support for 204 NoConent so far